# Create & return a default ImageFieldFile from inside a function

Tags: django, django-models

In my UserProfile model I would like to have a function which returns *either* the user's `ImageFileField` object or a default image if the user has not uploaded their own.

For example:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField('Headshot',blank=True,
                             upload_to=get_path_and_filename)

    def get_pic(self):
        if self.pic:
            return self.pic
        else:
            # return ImageFileField with a default value
```

I want to return an equivalent `ImageFileField` because I have filters that work with this object type (so I can't just pass it a string, easily) ... I tried looking at the [source code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py) but I can't quite figure out how to do it myself.

Is there an easy way to initialize a new `ImageFileField` object by passing it a path to an image file and then return it?

**PS:** I had thought about using a *default* setting for the ImageField, however, it seems less flexible because the file is stored at model creation ... and if I later want to change the default file, I would have to update all the database entries that had the old file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was probably a typo, but what you actually want to return is an `ImageFieldFile`.

The `ImageField` makes the property of the model instance actually aa `ImageFileDescriptor`. When you access the property, it returns an `ImageFieldFile` instance.

As long as you don't call the `save()` or `delete()` methods of the ImageFieldFile, you can instanciate one reasonably easily:

```
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFieldFile, FileField

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # ...

    def get_pic(self):
        if self.pic:
            return self.pic
        return ImageFieldFile(instance=None, field=FileField(),
                              name='pictures/default.jpg')
```

Comment: You are right, that was a dyslexic typo on my part (consistent, though, I might add).  I am just going to use the `get_pic` function in my templates ... hopefully this won't be too "unsafe".  I am going to give this a try tomorrow.  Looks like it will do what I want though.  I didn't realize that individual fields could be `save()` or `delete()` ... learn something every day!  Thank you.

Comment: That looks like it should work, but I am getting an error: 

    File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 23, in __init__
        self.storage = field.storage
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'storage'

If I change this to `field=self.pic` then it works okay; I tried to pass it an empty ImageField object but that didn't work.  Not sure if this is good, but it is working.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I lied, you can't use an ImageFieldFile just like that. Editing my answer...