# Default Image for Django easy_thumbnails

Tags: django, easy-thumbnails

I have a model with an ImageField that I display using easy_thumbnails (|thumbnail_url).
My question is how do I display a default image if the ImageField is empty?
I would like this logic in the Model/View, **NOT** in the html/template.

e.g.:

```
DEFAULT_PICTURE = 'default.jpg'

def get_picture(self):
    if self.picture:
        return self.picture
    else:
        from DEFAULT_PICTURE
```

What object should get_picture() return that is compatible with easy_thumbnails?
I tried to create a new File object, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield), but it did not work.
Can you kindly provide a working example of returning an existing file to display with easy_thumbnails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chris ([easy_thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails)) answered [here](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/issues/279), and also on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569698/create-return-a-default-imagefieldfile-from-inside-a-function).

His suggestion to create a new ImageFieldFile is good, but easy_thumbnails stilled failed because the newly created ImageFieldFile had an empty instance.
So either set `instance = self`:

```
DEFAULT_PICTURE = 'default.jpg'

def get_picture(self):
    if self.picture:
        return self.picture
    else:
        return ImageFieldFile(instance=self, field=FileField(), name=DEFAULT_PICTURE)
```

or change alias.py line 116:

```
if not hasattr(target, 'instance'):
    return None
```

should be...

```
if not hasattr(target, 'instance') or not target.instance:
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I have used previously. It could probably be optimized a bit (and probably shouldn't have the hard coded media path), but it worked well for my small project.

```
def get_picture(self):
    if self.picture:
         return '<img src="%s" />' % self.picture['thumbnail'].url
    return '{img src="/media/img/admin/icon-no.gif" alt="No Image"}'
```

With this, you just need to ensure that you have `icon-no.gif` in the appropriate path.

Comment: This returns HTML, without using easy_thumbnails pacakge